# write is not a function from useContractWrite

Tags: wagmi, wagmi-hooks, wagmi-react

I am getting this error in runtime when using usePrepareContractWrite my code is as follows from the wagmi documentation:

```
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
        address: "0x07a06AD39f......................"
        abi: [{ "inputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "operator",
                                "type": "address"
                            },
                            {
                                "internalType": "bool",
                                "name": "approved",
                                "type": "bool"
                            }
                        ],
                    "name": "setApprovalForAll",
                    "outputs": [],
                    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                    "type": "function"
                
            }],
        functionName: 'setApprovalForAll',
    });
    
    const { data, write } = useContractWrite(config)
    
    const { isLoading, isSuccess }= useWaitForTransaction({
        confirmations: 1,
        hash: data?.hash,
        onSuccess() {
            console.log("transaction success");
        }
    });
    
    const getPermission = async () => {
    ->    write({
                   args: ["0xaD1beE8B47464…………………………..", true],
                    from: address,
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the **usePrepareContractWrite** hook has finished executing before calling the **useContractWrite** hook. You can do this by checking the **isLoading** property of the **usePrepareContractWrite** hook.

Your end-user is connected to a wallet? It should be. You can do this by checking the **isConnected** property of the **wagmi** context.

Here is an example of how to check the **isLoading** property of the **usePrepareContractWrite** hook before calling the **useContractWrite** hook:

```
const { config, isLoading } = usePrepareContractWrite({
  address: "0x07a06AD39f......................",
  abi: [{
    "inputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "address",
        "name": "operator",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "internalType": "bool",
        "name": "approved",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "name": "setApprovalForAll",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  }],
  functionName: 'setApprovalForAll',
});

if (!isLoading) {
  const { data, write } = useContractWrite(config);

  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useWaitForTransaction({
    confirmations: 1,
    hash: data?.hash,
    onSuccess() {
      console.log("transaction success");
    }
  });

  const getPermission = async () => {
    write({
      args: ["0xaD1beE8B47464…………………………..", true],
      from: address,
    });
  }
}
```